# Get message in jquery - Dynamic Key

Tags: jsp, struts, jstl

In my jsp, I would show a message when I select an option, this message is loaded from a properties files. For example:

In props I have:

```
 msg.01=Message 1
 msg.02=Message 2
...
```

In Jquery code, I get the value of the selected option:

```
 $("#optionId').val()
```

And with Struts bean:message tag:

```
alert("<bean:message 
bundle='Message'`key='msg."+$("#clientTypeId').val()"+'/>");
```

The alert message showed is always:

`???en.msg.0x??? (x is 0 or 1 or ...)`

Have any idea about my problem please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure to tag question with specific tag else it will not able to get proper attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use JSTL when executing Javascript. What I would do is use JSTL to generate a Javascript object, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var messages = {
  <c:forEach begin="0" end="20" var="n" varStatus="s">
    ${s.first ? '' : ', '}
    <c:set var="key" value="${n gt 9 ? '' : '0'}${n}"/>
    <fmt:message key="msg.${key}" var="msg"/>
    "<c:out value="${key}"/>": "<c:out value="${msg}"/>"
  </c:forEach>
  };
</script>
```

Now you can get a message from the Javascript object:

```
alert(messages[$("#clientTypeId").val()]);
```